# Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback

Tags: plugin-development, functions

I create a new wordpress without theme and with only one plugin: GDPR WP. (I want to try this plugin on empty wordpress before deploy it on other website).

So, on a first time i try to create function to accept or not GoogleAnalytics cookie. My function work fine but i have on error on the BO/FO:

**Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'cookie_GA' not found or invalid function name in C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 286**

This is my function:

```
add_action( 'init', 'cookie_GA' );  

if (is_allowed_cookie('_ga')) {
    function cookie_GA() { ?>

        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-91484621-2"></script>
        <script>
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());

          gtag('config', 'UA-91484621-2');
        </script>

        <?php 
    };
};
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is clear:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, **function 'cookie_GA' not found or invalid function name** in C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 286

So `cookie_GA()` is not found. When can this be the case? Well, of course when `is_allowed_cookie('_ga')` is false. So either wrap the `add_action()` call inside that `if` as well or create a dummy function.

```
if (is_allowed_cookie('_ga')) {
    add_action( 'init', 'cookie_GA' );
    function cookie_GA() {  /* your code */ }
}
```

Comment: Beginner's mistake, thanks for your help. Its work

Comment: @TiboK You're welcome. If this was a typo-kinda mistake, feel free to delete the question altogether. If you think future visitors might find this usefil, please consider marking my answer as accepted